# Google sheet Formula for run down total for today's figures

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Attachment: my spreadsheet screen capture]

Hie Friends.
What formula can l use to calculate a total for today, then the same formula must detect the change of date tomorrow and start a new and fresh calculation which will be only for tomorrow. the next day it will repeat the same process by itself, automatically without being manually dragged down. lam looking for running total for Total Deposited, in Column "J". Currently lam using the formula: =sum($D$2:D5) for cell "J5".Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, clearly indicating the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `SUMIF`

If I have understood your setup properly it would need to be `=SUMIF(A:A,TODAY(),D:D)` although without seeing the full sheet with columns unhidden you may need to adjust the above to suit your requirments.

Answer (score 0):

use in J2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E, MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*E2:E), SIGN(E2:E)), IFERROR(1/0)))
```

[image]